# How to call a cms page in a phtml file in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need to display a CMS page inside my custom module's phtml file. Is there any way I can include it either through xml layout or via coding directly in phtml file? I know we can add a cms block but how can we add a cms page?

Comment: This link may help you , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218474/magento-add-cms-block-to-one-page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below code in your phtml file

```
 $page = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load('home_page','identifier');
 echo $page->getContent();
```

Comment: I have added a block to display contact page inside this CMS page. When I use this code it returns the block code that I have used in that CMS page instead of showing the contact page itself.

Comment: But the method you described does work if there is directly content inserted inside a CMS page. So it answers my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This code check if cms page is active then it will display page content

```
$page = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load('top_offer','identifier');

echo $page->getIsActive()?$page->getContent():'';
```