# Magento: Insert CMS Page inside the product description

Tags: magento

By using this code in the product description WYSIWYG editor, you can display a CMS block

```
{{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="01"}}
```

I am wondering, is there any way i can do the same with a CMS Page ?
Can i display a CMS page inside the product description from the  WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: You should use a static block for that and not a CMS page.  Any particular reason you want a CMS Page?

Comment: Yes, the particular reason it's because i have easy control over the layout and because i want to have a special design on the CMS page which if i put it in the static block, it will influence the whole design on the product page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own widget, see [Creating a Magento Widget](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-magento-widget-part-1)

Then implement your logic to get cms content

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    //get cms content from db
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will not work, since the product description is not passing the magento template filter system!

Answer (score 0):

there is a work around for it..you can try to pull the content of the cms page in your product view template file... ie in catalog/product/view.phtml file
refer here ([How to call a cms page in a phtml file in magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12816467/how-to-call-a-cms-page-in-a-phtml-file-in-magento?lq=1))